# How to download an unknown file name from an URL?

Tags: java

How do you download an unknown file name from an URL? I know how to download a file, the problem is the file name is unknown. 
I am trying to download the first ul/li inside a defined div. Thanks.

Comment: Can't you derive the file name from the URL? Then you will have to ask the user.

Comment: What you get from "downloading" from a URL is content. It's not a "file" until *you* write that content to disk, and then *you* get to name it anything you want. The server *might* give you a suggesting in the `filename` parm of the [`Content-Disposition`](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html#sec19.5.1) header, or it might not.

Comment: this might be a browser specific problem please indicate the browser. I think Safari does not tell you the file name or something. Indicate the browser you saw it on. what did you use to allow the user to insert the file was it an <input type='file'> show us the HTML/Java code you have so far.

Comment: How do you know the file name is unknown?  How do you normally determine the file name of a URL?

Comment: URL link = new URL("http://....../somefile.pdf"); link.openStream();   I don't know name of the pdf file, all I can tell is it's always the first link in the list.

Comment: Client keeps loading new files/links. I just need to select the top ul/li.

Comment: You seem to have 2 separate problems: first, parse the file name from a HTML page (first `<li>` in a `<ul>` in a `<div>`, like you say). Google "HTML parsing" or "web scraping". Once you have the file name, build the URL, e.g., by appending that file name to the base URL. Download by whatever means you prefer, e.g.Unix command line tools like `wget` or `curl`, or in Java with e.g., Apache's HTTP client (see https://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/tutorial.html)